# Use Scala with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, scala, azure-functions

Azure Functions currently supports the following [languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages): C#, JavaScript, F#, Java, Powershell, Python, Typescript. Scala is not on the list.

How can one use scala to write azure functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Azure Functions` supports Java. And it is pretty straight forward to make it working for scala:

```scala
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger

import java.util.Optional

class ScalaFunction {
  /**
   * This function listens at endpoint "/api/ScalaFunction"
   */
  @FunctionName("ScalaFunction")
  def run(
           @HttpTrigger(
             name = "req",
             methods = Array(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST),
             authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) request: HttpRequestMessage[Optional[String]],
           context: ExecutionContext): HttpResponseMessage = {
    context.getLogger.info("Scala HTTP trigger processed a request.")
    request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("This is written in Scala. Hello, ").build
  }
}
```

And this is how the pom.xml looks. There is an added dependency for scala and `maven-scala-plugin` plugin.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jp</groupId>
    <artifactId>AzurePrac</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.13.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.4.2</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>azureprac-20210906165023338</functionAppName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- function app name -->
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <!-- function app resource group -->
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    <!-- function app service plan name -->
                    <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                    <!-- function app region-->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                    <region>westus</region>
                    <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                    <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                    <!-- Whether to disable application insights, default is false -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details for all valid configurations for application insights-->
                    <!-- <disableAppInsights></disableAppInsights> -->
                    <runtime>
                        <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>8</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~3</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And finally to publish: `mvn clean package;  mvn azure-functions:deploy`