# REST API with methods using different programming languages

Tags: azure, rest, azure-web-app-service

- I assume that an App Service as part of an App Service Plan

  - could have methods not all in the same language.

Someone I work with stated you should have 2 App Services, e.g. one for python and one for Scala.
Is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone I work with stated you should have 2 App Services, e.g. one for python and one for Scala. Is this so?

Correct, you will need different App Services per runtime/language. They can share the same App Service Plan, if the runtime is supported by the Operating System of the App Service Plan.

A linux based App Service Plan gives the most choices, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview#built-in-languages-and-frameworks)

> Supported languages include: Node.js, Java (JRE 8 & JRE 11), PHP, Python, .NET Core, and Ruby.

If your runtime is not listened you could run a custom container on Azure Web App, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?tabs=dotnet&pivots=container-linux):

> [..] You can also use a custom Docker image to run your web app on an application stack that isn't already defined in Azure.

If web apps is a no go due to supported runtimes or other reasons there is a [myriad of other options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree) to host your api:

[image]

For simple api's [azure functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075094/use-scala-with-azure-functions) could also be a cost effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

No

You can have more than one app running on app service, each app runs in its own sandbox. Note that you will be charged on collective usage of resources on your app service. Although I can understand why one would want two independent app service plans - management is much simpler. You can scale your services independent of each other. If service A is being consumed 10 times more than service B, you have the flexibility of scaling it independently of the other service with it being on separate plan.

App service vs. VM - https://karansinghreen.medium.com/azure-virtual-machine-or-azure-app-service-which-one-should-you-choose-d4ba7d4a120d

VMs are preferable solution in certain scenarios. Not all languages are supported on app service plans.

Read more here about app services - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview

Comment: Also, this is probably duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734238/deploying-multiple-web-apps-on-azure-app-service-is-there-any-implications-of

Comment: I think you missed the important part in the question: it isn't so much about web apps/app service plans but about the supported runtimes.

Comment: @PeterBons I understand your point about runtime. When I wrote the response I had not seen your answer. Original question was asking about ability to host Python and Scala under single app service in a subscription. It is definitely possible. The run time limitation would come into effect if you choose two languages that are not compatible with one runtime. Again it is possible to overcome with single VM instead of app service.